# How to add a hook that adds a new tabs based on the word in the product title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want them to add tabs to the product with a description based on the word in the product title

I already have something created but based on tags but I don't know how to do that to add tabs based on the word in the title

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    if( has_term( 'Briliant', 'product_tag' ) )
    // Adds the new tab

    $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Tabela rozmiarów', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;

}
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {

    // The new tab content
    echo do_shortcode( '[block id="size-guide"]' );

}

I want him to add a new tabsa based on one word from the product title, not the tag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your question, but I think that solves your problem. with global $post you have access to the current post ie the product you can also get global $product if you want some information like values and so on.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    global $post;

    //add custom tab to product
    if (strpos($post->post_title, 'your title xyz') !== false) {
        $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
            'title'     => 'Tabela ' . $post->post_title,
            'priority'  => 50,
            'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
        );
    }

    return $tabs;

}
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {

    // The new tab content
    echo do_shortcode( '[block id="size-guide"]' );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I didn't really mean it. I have a product title:
 "xyz watch with a large red dial" 
I need a code that adds tabs to all products that contain the word xyz.